# Fill dynamic array with values from an array

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to execute a similar query on many tables. Instead of writing an *n* amount of almost similar similar queries, I would like to use a dynamic query. Pseudo:

```
array = (
    'table_a' => 'value_a',
    'table_b' => 'value_b',
    'table_c' => 'value_c'
);

foreach (array as table => value)
    exec(
        'select ' + @value + ' into #' + @table + ' from ' + @table
    );
end
```

Is something like this possible in SQL Server 2008 RE? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to insert these values into their respective tables ? The query itself as it is doesn't make much sense? More specifically what are you trying to achieve by this line of code `select ' + @value + ' into #' + @table + ' from ' + @table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in SQL Server using something like the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), tablename VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #temp
        ( tablename )
VALUES  ( 'table_a' ),('table_b'),('table_c')

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tblcount INT, @i INT = 1
SELECT @tblcount = MAX(id) FROM #temp

WHILE @i <= @tblcount
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT t.somefield, t.otherfield as ' + tablename + ' INTO #some_temptable_' + tablename + ' FROM #mytable t where SomeField like ''1''' FROM #temp WHERE id = @i
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        --SELECT @sql
        SELECT @i = @i + 1
    END

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: This probably is what I'm looking for. However, in reality my query should look like `'SELECT t.somefield, t.otherfield as '+  #temp.tablename + ' into #some_temptable_' + #temp.temptable + ' from #mytable t where SomeField like ' + id`. If I run this query, I get the error `The multi-part identifier "#tmp.tablename" could not be bound.` Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: What is `#temp`?  It looks like your temp table is called `#mytable`.

Comment: I updated my query: `'SELECT t.somefield, t.otherfield as '+  #temp.tablename + ' into #some_temptable_' + #temp.tablename + ' from #mytable t where SomeField like ' + id`. I agree it might be confusion. To be clear: `#temp` is your temp-table. `#mytable` is just another temp table I get data from. It could as well be a real table. Also `#some_temp_table` is yet another temp table from my side. The output of the first loop-iteration should therefore look like: `'SELECT t.somefield, t.otherfield as table_a into #some_temptable_table_a from #mytable t where SomeField like '1';`

Comment: If you're selecting from two temp tables, #temp and #mytable then they both need to be in the FROM clause, and they need to be joined appropriately.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I get confused as how I would have to join the tables since the #temp table basically holds no values to perform the join on?

Comment: Ok, based on your edit above I have updated the script.  I've also included a commented out `SELECT @sql` that you can use to view the statements instead of execute them.

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. I now get a `Incorrect syntax near '<'`? Please see the split-off post for my exact code (it does not yet contain your update) because this original question is basically answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187422/create-a-list-of-dymanic-queries-from-an-array-in-sql-server-2008