# Create a list of dynamic queries from an array in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I split this question of from [Fill dynamic array with values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184180/fill-dynamic-array-with-values-from-an-array/24185288). Below is the actual code I now have.

First the dynamic code, second the 3 example queries that I would like the dynamic code to output (but which it doesn't). I get an error `Invalid column name "field"` or, when I change `field` into `#tmp_auditlog_fields.field`, the error that `the column "field" cannot be bound`. The latter error is probably due to me not joining any tables but I have no clue on which field to join the tables since the `#tmp_auditlogs_fields` is nothing more than an array to create a bunch of queries, unrelated to any real data in the database.

How can I get the desired output? Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

```
-- dynamic code

create table #tmp_auditlog_fields (
  id int identity(1,1),
  field varchar(255),
  details varchar(255)
);

insert into #tmp_auditlog_fields (field, details) values
    ('a', 'foo'),
    ('b', 'bar'),
    ('c', 'baz'),
;

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @cnt int, @i int = 1;

select @cnt = max(id) from #tmp_auditlog_fields;

while @i <= @cnt
    begin
        select @sql = 
            'select t.objectID, t.DocID as ' + field + 
            ' into #tmp_auditlog_' + field + 
            ' from #tmp_auditlog_subselection t where Details like ' + 
            details FROM  tmp_auditlog_fields WHERE id = @i
        exec sp_executesql @sql
        select @i = @i + 1
    end 
;

-- example queries

select t.ObjectID, t.DocID as a 
into #tmp_auditlog_a from #tmp_auditlog_subselection t
where Details like 'foo';

select t.ObjectID, t.DocID as b 
into #tmp_auditlog_b from #tmp_auditlog_subselection t
where Details like 'bar';

select t.ObjectID, t.DocID as c 
into #tmp_auditlog_c from #tmp_auditlog_subselection t
where Details like 'baz';
```

SQL Fiddle attempt:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @id int;

create table #tmp_auditlog_subselection (
  stuff varchar(255),
  other varchar(255)
);

insert into #tmp_auditlog_subselection (stuff, other) values
  ('foo', 'bar'),
  ('baz', 'bat'),
  ('lorem', 'ipsum')
;

create table #tmp_auditlog_fields (
  id int identity(1,1),
  field varchar(255),
  details varchar(255)
);

insert into #tmp_auditlog_fields (field, details) values
  ('a', 'foo'),
  ('b', 'bar'),
  ('c', 'baz')
;

while exists(select * from #tmp_auditlog_fields where id >= @id)
    begin
        select @sql = 
            'select t.objectID, t.DocID as ' + field + 
            ' into #tmp_auditlog_' + field + 
            ' from #tmp_auditlog_subselection t where Details like ' + 
            details FROM tmp_auditlog_fields WHERE id = @i;
        exec @sql
        select @id = min(id) from #tmp_auditlog_fields where id > @id;
    end 
;

select * from #tmp_auditlog_a;
```

Comment: Add a `FROM #tmp_auditlog_fields` after your `select @sql = ...`.  The current query doesn't know what table to pull your `field` and `details` columns from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the from statement and where statement here:

```
while @i <= @cnt
    begin
        select @sql = 
            'select t.objectID, t.DocID as ' + field + 
            ' into #tmp_auditlog_' + field + 
            ' from #tmp_auditlog_subselection t where Details like ' + details FROM #tmp_auditlog_fields WHERE id = @i
        exec sp_executesql @sql
        select @i = @i + 1
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, the code now run flawlessly. However, when I perform a `select * from #tmp_auditlog_foo` I get the error `Invalid object name '#tmp_auditlog_foo'`? So the question would be: are dynamically generated #temp tables accessible outside the of the while loop?

Comment: They should be - you could try global temp tables instead: `##temp_auditlog_foo`

Comment: Not to annoy you, but I have tried all possible ways (selecting the temp table inside the while loop, outside, global temp) but I keep getting the same error. I have updated the OP. Can you confirm it works on your system?

Comment: I tried to create an SQLFiddle example but when building the schema it gets stuck on `Schema Creation Failed: Must declare the scalar variable "@cnt".:`. I don't understand why, because I have selected the right database (SQL Server 2008) and on my server that bit works fine. I have included the SQL Fiddle code I used in the OP.

Comment: When I try to run on my machine I get two errors: Extra comma after     `('b', 'bar'),
    ('c', 'baz'),
;` and also missing pound sign from here: `details FROM  tmp_auditlog_fields WHERE id = @i`

Comment: Temp tables created within dynamic sql are scoped only within that dynamic sql.  Temp tables created outside of the dynamic sql are scoped such that the current session as well as the dynamic session can access it.  Global temp tables are an alternative, however, as Dave.Gugg suggested.

Comment: I updated my SQL Fiddle attempt but I keep getting the error `must declare scalar variable @id` even though I do this at the very top. Is there something wrong with the SQLFiddle SQL Server 2008 parser?

Comment: I have not used SQL Fiddle much.  During my test attempts just now, it appears that using `;` seems to be breaking up the batches issued and is causing the variables to fall out of scope.

Comment: Deleting the semicolons worked! :D Thanks! Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e4e5 -> `invalid object name '##tmp_auditlog_a`. Am I using global temp tables wrong?

Comment: Your fiddle link did not have any temp tables.  I tried to recreate what I think you wanted here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcae9/20